# how to interrupt arduino when data recieved via rx pin

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino

```
what am I doing wrong ? I have the RX of the Bluetooth HC-07 wired into pin2 looking for a change in voltage when data is received to start a interrupt. 

I'm trying to cause an interrupt when data is received via the Bluetooth.     


    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library
    #include <PinChangeInt.h>


    SoftwareSerial Genotronex(10, 11); // RX, TX
    int ledpin=13; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
    int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer
    void doSomething(void);

    void setup() {
      // wil run once
      Genotronex.begin(9600);// data rate for comunicating 
      Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
      pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);


      interrupts();
      pinMode(2,INPUT);
      attachInterrupt(0,doSomething,  CHANGE);
    }

    void loop() {
      // Main body of code


    }



    void doSomething(){
     Genotronex.println("INTERRUPT!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    digitalWrite(ledpin,1);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledpin,0);
    delay(1000);

    detachInterrupt(0);

    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This is a repost of the code ,, I've taken out what the comments said and added what you recommended,, for the most part. The code runs but change state never changes back it only changes once? I've tried taking out DetachInterrupt but the actual interrupt stops working then  ? Any more ideas? Thanks for the help btw

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library



SoftwareSerial Genotronex(10, 11); // RX, TX
int ledpin=13; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer
void doSomething(void);
volatile int state = LOW;


void setup() {
  // wil run once
  Genotronex.begin(9600);// data rate for comunicating 
  Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please press 1 or 0 blink LED ..");
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);



  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0,doSomething,  CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  // Main body of code
digitalWrite(ledpin, state);

}



void doSomething(){

Genotronex.println("INTERRUPT!!!!!!!!!!!!");



 state = !state;



detachInterrupt(0);

}
```

Comment: How do you know the interrupt is not firing? See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt. delay relies on interrupts itself, so may not be used inside an ISR. Follow the example at the bottom of the page above and see if the interrupt works.

Comment: Does ledpin go on solid? Place a interrupts(); first thing in void doSomething() { interrupts(); ...   This will re-enable the MilliSecond Overflow Interrupt.

Comment: May not be critical but just FYI or cautionary - PinChangeInt.h should not be needed. SoftwareSerial.h handles these internally. It may re-write the ISR vector for PCINT that softwareSerial.h uses. breaking your serial Rx from the GPS.  And pinMode(2,INPUT); is already by default. interrupts(); in setup will be done by attachInterrupt(...);

Comment: Thanks for these comments I've followed them . It works but it only changes state once? I've taken out DetachInterrupt but then it doesnt run the intterupt? any ideas? cheers for the help btw.  (Ive repost the code above)

Comment: remember that serial data will have many toggles. That will cause repeats of INT0. And also note that SoftwareSerial uses PCINT's. Which are superseded by INT0. So the detachInterrupt(0) prevents these to from colliding, after the first start bit. You will need to re-attach it after the reception is completed.

Comment: FYI for UART 8N1 the start bit is always a zero after idle 1. So changing CHANGE to FALLING will cut the possible interrupts in half.

Answer (score 1):

delete:
`detachInterrupt(0);`

If you can change interrupt from CHANGE to HIGH/LOW and add something like 'debouncing'. My version here (HIGH state interrupts):

```
void interruptfunction() { 

      //your interrupt code here

  while(1){
    if (digitalRead(2)==LOW){
      delay(50);
      if (digitalRead(2)==LOW) break;
    }
  }
}
```

Or this: (not tested)

```
void interruptfunction() { 

      //your interrupt code here

  if (digitalRead(2)==HIGH) state=true;
  else state=false;

  while(1){
    if (digitalRead(2)!=state){
      delay(50);
      if (digitalRead(2)!=state) break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have to react on CHANGE try leaving `detachInterrupt(0);` but reattach it somewhere in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see more problems you have in the code:

1. you declare "state" value as int and then you reverse bits with "state = !state" (I am not sure this can work)
2. you call a function println in the interrupt function... this is not suitable approach. Do not solve your code in the interrupt function. Use it only to set a boolean and control things in the loop function with this. For example:

   void doSomething() { isInterrupt = true; }

   void loop() {

   if (isInterrupt) {

   Genotronex.println("INTERRUPT!!!!!!!!!!!!");

   if (digitalRead(2) == LOW)

   digitalWrite(2, HIGH);

   else digitalWrite(2, LOW);

   isInterrupt = false;

   }

   }